# Django unit tests not executing django signals from original model

Tags: python, django

I am creating few django tests and one of the test needs to post the data to certain url as soon as new model gets created or updated and I am using djnago signals for dispatching them in my models.py file.

Now when I create new object or the modify existing object from shell, I get the post request to the target url with specified data and thus working completely fine.

However, when I write statements to create or update the model in django tests it doesn't do anything, It just create the object in alias database but does not actually send any signal to target url

Here is how my django test look like:

```
class ProductEndpointTests(APITestCase):

    def test_product_create(self):

        productobject = Product.objects.create(title="pr1",
                             description="good deal",
                             price=19.99)
        productobject.save()
```

Models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)

def product_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    product = instance
    # Post data to given url

post_save.connect(product_post_save, sender=Product)
```

Is there anything that I am missing or do I need to add anything in django test in order to dispatch signals from tests?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 productobject = Product.objects.create(title="pr1",
                             description="good deal",
                             price=19.99)
 alertobject.save()
```

Where is `productobject.save()`? I see you're calling `alertobject.save()`.

Use `productobject.save()` and it should work fine.

Comment: okay that was a typo, sorry about that, I have edited the post

Comment: what's happening now? where is your assertion related code?

Comment: So, its not dispatching the signals for some reason when I create model object in test, the assertion code is not implemented yet because I am not yet getting any post request to the target url after object being created, as soon as it can do the post request I can implement some assertion to validate